# Gulpfile doesn't create bundle.js

Tags: reactjs, gulp

I'm having some problems with my gulpfile

```
"use strict"

var gulp = require("gulp")
var browserify = require("browserify")
var source = require("vinyl-source-stream")
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload')
var watchify = require('watchify')

gulp.task("default", () => {
    livereload.listen()
    var bundler = browserify("./src/components/index.jsx")
        .plugin(watchify, {ignoreWatch: './src/components/*'})
        .transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
    bundle(bundler)
    bundler.on('update', function () {
        bundle(bundler)
    })
})

function bundle(bundler) {

  bundler
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js')) // Set source name
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./public/dist"))
    .pipe(livereload()); // Reload the view in the browser
}
```

When I execute it using `gulp`I get the following messages

> [02:06:23] Using gulpfile ~/react-rpi/gulpfile.js
>
> [02:06:23] Starting
>
> 'default'... [02:06:23] Finished 'default' after 24 ms

But bundle.js is not created. Any key? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you try this?

```
function bundle(bundler) {  
    return bundler.bundle().on('error', function (err) {
        console.error(err.message)
        this.emit('end')
    })
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/dist/js/'))
    .pipe(plugins.livereload()) 
}
```

Then you can see what's happening

Comment: Thanks! I have added the error manager on my code and now I see where is the error :D

Comment: Here a bootstrap file on how to do it with webpack https://github.com/jsdario/react-es6-webpack-base